# Bounding boxes and models

Tags: c++, models, bounding

I've made a basic .obj mesh loader that can load models and texture them in OpenGL. However, my question is what would be the best solution to then put bounding boxes on them. For example if I a load a model which is a circle, would putting an AABB around it be a terrible solution?

My idea is to make an object have a global AABB box then the model also has a list of more perfect bounding boxes.

My question is, what should I use to make this list of more perfected bounding boxes?

Comment: What's the purpose of all of these bounding volumes? What's wrong with just using an axis-aligned bounding box?

Comment: I was thinking, that when you load in a model I could create a general AABB around the object. But then have smaller more detailed bounding boxes around certain parts to get a better collision detection. So for example if i load in a model that is sphere shaped then put a AABB around that the collision detection wouldnt be so perfect. Where as if the AABB was the general box then if a collision happened with that box it would then check the objects actual collision boxes.

Comment: So what does that have to do with OpenGL? OpenGL doesn't do collision detection.

Comment: I suppose because the models are being loading and draw using OpenGL however I removed that tag anyways

Comment: Assuming this is for collision detection, don't waste your time on finding perfect bounding elements. AABBs (possibly in a hierarchy) will work just fine. And you could always go for k-DOPs or OBBs later on. The point is not the get the perfect bounding volume, but a way to easily reduce the number of elementary tests.

Comment: Do you think, when I load in a model I create one AABB box for the whole model, then for every 10ish faces create one k-DOP face in some kind of structore. Then when an object for example is inside the models AABB then use the k-DOP faces test if the collision has occured?

Comment: You would normally construct a hierarchy (bottom up or top down) of bounding elements (Just pick one. No reason to mix) using some appropriate heuristic. You want to ensure a well balanced tree that is easily traversed. I would highly recommend you read "Real-time Collision Detection" by Christer Ericson if you're interested in such topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about "more perfect bounding boxes" for your collision detection. That is not the point of them. What you want is a bounding element - and possibly a hierarchy of them - which allows you to easily test for intersections and reject large sets of polygons/elements on which you don't need to perform your elementary intersection tests.

I would say, start out with your AABBs (or even bounding spheres, for the simplicity of them). And either top down, or bottom up (using some appropriate heuristic) construct a tree out of them. Your top node has your large AABB which fits your entire model. And each branch (with its AABB) contains an ever smaller subset of your mesh. You want the final tree to be well balanced.

Should you notice that your AABBs cause problems (as in, not enough performance perhaps), then you can always select other bounding elements. OBBs or k-DOPs perhaps. In our garment simulation code for example k-DOPs have shown to be a good fit.

In any case, you might want to look up the book "Real-time collision detection". It goes into this topic in depth and is IMHO an excellent resource if you're interested in a topic like this. But just keep things simple at first. Make them work, then worry about optimization.